# how do i make the square go up in :hover after the animation ends?

Tags: animation, overriding, transition

i use separate tags for transition and animation, but still they dont work together
i need the red square to lift up after being hovered over with a cursor after the animation ends

i wanted to make both animation and transition happen
it didnt happen

```
         <div class="box fadein hoverpop"></div>
```

```
div{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
}
 .fadein{
    animation: fadein 0.4s forwards;
}
@keyframes fadein {
    0%{
        transform: translateY(20px);
    }
    100%{
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }
} 
.hoverpop{
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.hoverpop:hover{
    transform: translateY(20px);
}
```